# Pytorch: Weights not changing during training

Tags: python, pytorch

Basically the same question as this one here, which was never answered: [Why the first convolutional layer weights don't change during training?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39613377/why-the-first-convolutional-layer-weights-dont-change-during-training)

I just want to watch the weights of my convolutional layers as they change during training. How can I do this? No matter what I do, the weights seem to stay the same even though loss is decreasing.

I'm trying to follow this tutorial here although the model is slightly different: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html#sphx-glr-beginner-blitz-cifar10-tutorial-py

### Model

```py
class CNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Digit_Classifier, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1,6,3)
        self.pool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6,16,3)
        self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(2)
        self.out = nn.Linear(400, 10)

    def forward(self, inputs):
        x = self.pool1(F.relu(self.conv1(inputs)))
        x = self.pool2(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = torch.flatten(x, start_dim=1)
        x = self.out(x)
        return x
```

### Training

```py
def train(epochs=100):
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    net = CNN()
    optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)
    losses = []
    
    for epoch in range(epochs):  # loop over the dataset multiple times

        running_loss = 0.0
        for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
            # get the inputs; data is a list of [inputs, labels]
            inputs, labels = data

            # zero the parameter gradients
            optimizer.zero_grad()

            outputs = net(inputs)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            running_loss += loss.item()            
            w = model.conv1._parameters['weight']
            print(w)            

            losses.append(running_loss / z)
            if i % 2000 == 1999:    # print every 2000 mini-batches
                print('[%d, %5d] loss: %.3f' % (epoch + 1, i + 1, running_loss / 2000))
                running_loss = 0.0
    return net
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use any normalization modules, the closer the weights are to the input of the network, the smaller the gradients and therefore the changes will be, so the changes are probably in the decimals that aren't displayed anymore in your `print()` statement. To see the changes, I'd suggest saving the weights from one iteration to the next, and subtracting them to display the difference:

```
...
w = model.conv1._parameters['weight'].detach()
print(w-w_previous)
w_previous = w
...
```

Comment: This prints a tensor with all 0s which confirms my suspicion that the weights aren't updating. How can i go about normalizing?

Comment: Alternatively use `(w-w_previous).abs().sum()` to compute the 1-norm. For normalization the most popular choices are `nn.BatchNorm2d()` or `nn.InstanceNorm2d()` etc.